# asp.net Web farming

Tags: asp.net

I have a query in enabling the web farm.I have server A and server B.I have enabled  web farming(stateserver).Do i need to run the asp.net state server in two machine A and B?
or can i point the ipaddress to one server.

Advance Thanks
sanju

Answer (score 3):

only one of the two machines needs to be running state server

once this is done, you would need to setup the following in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState
        mode="StateServer"
        stateConnectionString="tcpip=your_server_ip:42424"
        cookieless="false"
        timeout="20" />
</system.web>
```

a good walkthrough of the whole process is available here:
http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-%28aspnet_state%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must have exactly one state management server for the whole farm. It's not better than `Inproc` else.

Answer (score 0):

### Single state server

You should configure a single server as your **State server** and point your web servers to it. This way, they'll share the same session.

If you'd use multiple state servers, they can't share their data between themselves.